# skipping consecutive alerts

Tags: python, skip

I'm trying to formulate a logic for the following table

```
Hour|Alert_Flag
---------------
6   |0 
7   |1 
8   |1 
9   |1 
10  |0
11  |1 
where Alert_Flag=1 means raise an alert and Alert_Flag=0 means no alert raised
```

What i want to accomplish here is to raise an alert at 7 since the Alert_flag is set to 1, but then not raise an alert for the subsequent hours uptil 10, since the alert was already raised for 7

The next alert should be raised at 11, since there was a break in between.

How can I pythonically represent this?

I'm new to programming, would be great if anyone could help

Comment: Please provide some code so we know exactly what you trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some clues to solve it yourself:

```
alerts = [(6, 0), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 0), (11, 1)]

clock_state = 1
for item in alerts:
    hour, alert_flag = item

    if alert_flag != clock_state:
        print "Clock not ringing at {0}".format(hour)
    else:
        print "Clock ringing at {0}".format(hour)
        clock_state = not clock_state
```

One little advice though, next time try to show some code you've attempted, even if it's not working, people here don't like questions with shows any effort to solve the problems.

**EDIT**

If you want to show only changes from 0->1, here you go:

```
alerts = [(6, 0), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 0), (11, 1)]
len_alerts = len(alerts)

for index in range(len_alerts - 1):
    hour1, alert_flag1 = alerts[index]
    hour2, alert_flag2 = alerts[index + 1]

    if alert_flag1 == 0 and alert_flag2 == 1:
        print "Clock ringing at {0}".format(hour2)
```

Comment: The code will make the clock ring at every change 0 to 1 and 1 to 0, the question specifically asks for alert only when there is a specific change from 0 to 1

Comment: @cmidi I didn't want to show that to him in the first place... but if you insist I've just edited. Sometimes is good if you only give little clues to the beginners

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your alert flags are in a list:

```
for i in range(len(alert_flags)-1):
    if alert_flags[i] == 0 and alert_flags[i+1] == 1:
        # code to raise an alert
```

Comment: The code does not work if there is there is an alert on index 0. The question just wants to mute the consecutive alerts.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

hour_alerts = OrderedDict([
    ("6", 0),
    ("7", 1),
    ("8", 1),
    ("9", 1),
    ("10", 0),
    ("11", 1)
])

raiseAlert = 0

for each in hour_alerts.keys():
    if hour_alerts[each]== 0:
        raiseAlert = 1
    elif (hour_alerts[each] and raiseAlert):
        print "alerting after break"
        raiseAlert = 0
```

There are many ways to do this. This is just one way.
Also echo @BPL comments about showing your efforts

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is store a state of the previous alert, below is a quick example to show that, alerts only when the alert flag is set and previous seen alert flag was not set.

```
for i,n in enumerate(alerts):
    if n == 1 and (i==0 or alerts[i-1] == 0):
        print "Alert on",i
```